# Using Survey123 pulldata() function on ArcGIS Online hosted Feature Service layer

Tags: javascript, arcgis-online, web-service, arcgis-survey123, arcgis-survey123-connect

I am trying to populate fields with attributes from my feature layer service hosted on ArcGIS Online. I am using the JavaScript sample template available on Survey123 Connect and following along with the Working with web services section of [this blog post](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-survey123-blog/extending-survey123-smart-forms-with-custom-js/ba-p/898782) about the pulldata() function.

When I use the web service [url provided](https://services.arcgis.com/P3ePLMYs2RVChkJx/arcgis/rest/services/World_Administrative_Divisions/FeatureServer/0) in the template my survey works as expected (populates fields with attributes of the feature that intersects with the geopoint). When I try with my own url from ArcGIS Online nothing happens. Am I missing something when publishing my layer as a feature service? It is shared with my organization and I am signed-in to Survey123. My URL looks like this: https://services6.arcgis.com/1QLe7xIMQ0LfJiB1/arcgis/rest/services/XXXXXXXXXX/FeatureService/0

Comment: Any luck with this one? I'm having similar issues with that function...works for other layers but not my published datasets.

Answer (score 1):

Although a bit off-topic, please note that you can save yourself some time if you consider using Javascript, that Javascript functions are disabled when used outside your organisation or used on a public (non-login) survey.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is not required anymore:

> The pulldata("@layer") function was introduced with Survey123 version 3.16 (October 2022). It allows you to query an ArcGIS layer and retrieve data from it ... [and] simplifies the syntax for querying ArcGIS layers, and it can be used in public surveys too!

Source: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-survey123-blog/survey123-tricks-of-the-trade-pulldata-quot-layer/ba-p/1224415